# Declaratively mocking a custom LWC in a single unit test

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-jest

The approaches suggested of using jestconfig module mapper or the **mocks** folder work well if you have a single mock per component you are testing, but not if you have to build how your parent component interacts with a child components in different scenario.

I would like to create a custom mock of my component in a specific jest test like so:

```
jest.mock('c/my-component', 
() => {
  return {
    default: jest.fn(),
    myExternalMethod: jest.fn( () => 'something')
  };
},
{ virtual: true })
```

however the following approach fails like so:

```
   Assert Violation: c() 2nd argument Ctor must be a function.
```

I imagine this is somehow related to the fact that c/my-component extends LightningComponent, but I cannot find any documentation about this. What is the right way to mock a specific custom LWC in a specific test?

Comment: This is now answered by https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/399892/how-do-i-mock-a-child-lwc-in-a-parents-jest-unit-test

Answer (score 0):

Answer replicated from: [How do I mock a child LWC in a parent's Jest Unit Test?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/399892/how-do-i-mock-a-child-lwc-in-a-parents-jest-unit-test)

Let's say we have two components `parentComponent` and `childComponent`.

`parentComponent` includes `childComponent` in its template:

```
<template>
    <c-child-component
        child-property={aValue}
        other-child-property={anotherValue}
    ></c-child-component>
</template>
```

In order to mock `childComponent` **only** in the test for `parentComponent` we need to:

- Build a skeleton stub for `childComponent` as a JS file.
- Instruct the `parentComponent` test to use this file instead of the real `childComponent`.

**Build a skeleton stub for `childComponent` as a JS file.**

- Create a folder inside the `childComponent`'s folder named `__mocks__`.
- Inside that folder, create a file `childComponent.js`, copying the contents of the real component into it.  You should end up with a folder structure like:

```
    lwc
        childComponent
            __mocks__
                childComponent.js
            __tests__
                childComponent.test.js
            childComponent.html
            childComponent.js
            childComponent.js-meta.xml
```

- Strip out everything from the new file other than the class definition and `@api` defined properties.  E.g:

```
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';

export default class SaveEntityForm extends LightningElement
{
    @api childProperty;
    @api otherChildProperty;
}
```

- Ensure that the **mocks** folders are ignored when you perform a push by adding `**/__mocks__/**` into your .forceignore.   E.g. it may look like:

```
package.xml

# LWC configuration files
**/jsconfig.json
**/.eslintrc.json

# LWC Jest
**/__tests__/**
**/__mocks__/**
```

**Instruct the `parentComponent` test to use this file instead of the real `childComponent`.**

- At the top of the unit test for `parentComponent`, tell Jest to use the mock version of `childComponent` by calling `jest.mock` passing the Salesforce style import path of the component.  E.g. the top of your test file may look like:

```
import { createElement } from 'lwc';
import ParentComponent from 'c/parentComponent';

jest.mock( 'c/childComponent' ); // Uses the mock version of childComponent defined in the __mocks__ directory of that LWC

describe( 'c-parent-component', () => {
    // your tests...
}
```

(thanks to https://tigerfacesystems.com/blog/lwc-nested-component-testing for the solution to this problem)