# How do I mock a child LWC in a parent's Jest Unit Test?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-jest, mock

I have two components that are in my app:

- parentComponent
- childComponent.

'parentComponent' includes 'childComponent' as a component.

E.g: `parentComponent.html`

```
<template>
    <c-child-component
        child-property={aValue}
        other-child-property={anotherValue}
    ></c-child-component>
</template>
```

Child component is non-trivial, and maybe includes some `@wire` methods or imperative calls to Apex.

Therefore, when writing the Jest unit test for `parentComponent` we want to mock `childComponent` so we don't have to worry about its complex behaviour - particularly when it references the database.

The Salesforce documentation (at time of writing) describes mocking LWCs in both the following links:

- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.unit_testing_using_jest_patterns
- https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/test-lightning-web-components/mock-other-components

This involves creating a `jest.config.js` file and defining `moduleNameMapper` references.

Unfortuantely, this will change the behaviour of the import so that it includes the mock version *in all tests*.

In the described situation, we have build `childComponent` and therefore need to also test this component - and so we can't use that technique.

So - **How can I mock `childComponent` *only* in the unit test for `parentComponent`?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to mock `childComponent` **only** in the test for `parentComponent` we need to:

- Build a skeleton stub for `childComponent` as a JS file.
- Instruct the `parentComponent` test to use this file instead of the real `childComponent`.

**Build a skeleton stub for `childComponent` as a JS file.**

- Create a folder inside the `childComponent`'s folder named `__mocks__`.
- Inside that folder, create a file `childComponent.js`, copying the contents of the real component into it.  You should end up with a folder structure like:

```
    lwc
        childComponent
            __mocks__
                childComponent.js
            __tests__
                childComponent.test.js
            childComponent.html
            childComponent.js
            childComponent.js-meta.xml
```

- Strip out everything from the new file other than the class definition and `@api` defined properties.  E.g:

```
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';

export default class ChildComponent extends LightningElement
{
    @api childProperty;
    @api otherChildProperty;

    @api doThing() {}  // include any @api annotated methods
}
```

- Ensure that the **mocks** folders are ignored when you perform a push by adding `**/__mocks__/**` into your .forceignore.   E.g. it may look like:

```
package.xml

# LWC configuration files
**/jsconfig.json
**/.eslintrc.json

# LWC Jest
**/__tests__/**
**/__mocks__/**
```

**Instruct the `parentComponent` test to use this file instead of the real `childComponent`.**

- At the top of the unit test for `parentComponent`, tell Jest to use the mock version of `childComponent` by calling `jest.mock` passing the Salesforce style import path of the component.  E.g. the top of your test file may look like:

```
import { createElement } from 'lwc';
import ParentComponent from 'c/parentComponent';

jest.mock( 'c/childComponent' ); // Uses the mock version of childComponent defined in the __mocks__ directory of that LWC

describe( 'c-parent-component', () => {
    // your tests...
}
```

**Stretch goal: Mocking methods that exist on the child component.**

- If you need to then check that methods are called on your child component, then you can grab the child from the parent component and configure a mock function for any that you are interested in.

For example:

```
describe('c-parent-component', () => {

    beforeEach( () => {
        const element = createElement('c-parent-component', {
            is: ParentComponent
        });

        document.body.appendChild( element );
    })

    it( 'Child component is called', () => {

        const element = document.body.querySelector( 'c-parent-component' );
        const child = element.shadowRoot?.querySelector( 'c-child-component' ); // Get the child component from the parent's DOM
        child.doThing = jest.fn();  // override the method on child to be a mock.  You can define its behaviour at this point too.

        return Promise.resolve()
            .then( () => element.shadowRoot?.querySelector( 'lightning-button' ).click() )
            .then( () => {
                expect( child.doThing ).toHaveBeenCalledTimes( 1 );  // check that the child method was called.  You can check parameters were passed, etc.
            })
    });

}
```

Note: in general, I would use more identifying characteristics on the component other than simply the type of HTML element it is.  E.g. I would add a data-id or data-name and use that instead.

(thanks to https://tigerfacesystems.com/blog/lwc-nested-component-testing for the basic solution to this problem)

Comment: You might want to include an example of the child component having a public `@api` function that's mocked as well

Comment: That's a good shout, although that might be a whole additional question in its own right!

Comment: I succumbed to the pressure...